# (Friendly_id) How to use slug instead of id in nested routes?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

I have two models - Team and Campaign.

Team `has_many :campaigns` & Campaign `belongs_to :team`

Using friend_id gem, I have my team routes working as expected i.e https://localhost/t/myteam

However, for `campaign_path(@campaign.team, @campaign)` my url shows up as http://localhost/t/1/campaign/1 while I am expecting it to be http://localhost/t/myteam/campaign/1

How can I achieve this? What am I doing wrong?

Sharing snippet of my routes code.

```
resources :teams, :path => 't' do
  member do
    get :new_invite
    resources :campaigns, :path => 'c' do
      member do
        get :share_callback
        get :enter
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Campaign.rb

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :campaign_heading, use: :slugged
belongs_to :team
```

Team.rb

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :slug, use: :slugged
```

Comment: can you post the routes file (only the part related is enough)?

Comment: @AnaMaríaMartínezGómez updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it more explicit:

```
team_campaign_path(team_id: @campaign.team.slug, @campaign)
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the route a resourced route?. If it is, then you need to set the param key to slug. Like this:

```
resources :campaigns, param: :slug
```

Comment: This is not needed when using the frendly_id gem. Check: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id